# How to get sub-menus of current node?

Tags: routes, navigation

I have created a `basic page` - **"About Us"** and provided it a **menu link** under `Main menu`.
Now I have created 3 more `basic page` as *sub-menu* of **About us**.

So, the hierarchy is like:

```
> Main Menu
> 
> --About Us
> ----sub-menu1
> ----sub-menu2
> ----sub-menu3
```

**Now, what I want to achieve is**, when **"About us"** menu is clicked, all its **sub-menus should rendered at left**, in sidebar left block and its related content on right.

Also when I click sub-menu1, **page should not get refresh**. i.e; the url should become something like: about-us/sub-menu1.

I know, this url is possible if I use About-Us as content type. But I'm using it as basic page.

**Any suitable approach to achieve this?**

Comment: `Also when I click sub-menu1, page should not get refresh` if you don't want the page to refresh, then you need to use **ajax**. For changing the url [Change browser address bar URL with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497677/change-browser-address-bar-url-with-jquery)

Comment: if you need more help let me know, just feeling lazy to write this answer.